Create a Realm, Clients and Users under it via keycloak admin API
I am trying to create a complete Realm with client (public and private) and users. I am able to create realm with the token got from another realm. i.e., I am able to call the API {{base_path}}/admin/realms and create API with another realm client token (with realm creation permission client).
But with the same token that used to create realm i am not able to call client creation API  {{base_path}}/admin/realms/{{realm_name}}/clients or user creation API {{base_path}}/admin/realms/{{realm_name}}/users.
Any idea how to achieve this? Or am I missing anything?

I need to know what error code you're getting exactly but usually it's because of insufficient permissions. In order to check what you can do with your JWT, you can decode your JWT here.
For example, this is a decoded JWT:
{
  "exp": 1726550959,
  "iat": 1726550239,
  "jti": "814bad70-2db3-46fb-a535-46a0bb526f60",
  "iss": "http://192.168.0.11:18080/auth/realms/camunda-platform",
  "aud": [
    "realm-management",
    "tasklist-api",
    "zeebe-api",
    "operate-api",
    "web-modeler-api",
    "admin-cli",
    "optimize-api",
    "web-modeler-public-api",
    "camunda-identity-resource-server",
    "broker",
    "account"
  ],
  "sub": "b27ac7e2-05f9-485b-a184-da50f0759bd0",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "react-app",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "192.168.0.8/*"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "Tasklist",
      "realm-admin",
      "Default user role",
      "offline_access",
      "Operate",
      "uma_authorization",
      "Identity",
      "Optimize",
      "Zeebe",
      "Web Modeler"
    ]
  },
...

As you can see, you can identify whether or not your token is expired or has access to the resources you need. For instance, check the aud (audience) section above.
But before that, I'd check the request with a token from the master realm. If it worked, you can make sure the endpoint and headers are correct. Then, you can go to the admin console and enable the necessary roles and give required permissions to your client.

Audiences are from the other realm.  Because client i used to generate from is from another realm. Checked the necessary permissions (roles assigned), which looks good for me. Will check with the master realm token. But in my scenario master token usage is not possible.
